# Scroll to down in textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    Hello
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <textarea id="one" class="inner">
    Goodbye
</textarea>
</div>

$("#one").append("your text to append");
$("#one").append("your text to append");
$("#one").append("your text to append");
$("#one").append("your text to append");
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/tGFmq/

how can i make automatically scroll to down in this textarea?

Comment: And you're sure there are no previous questions on this topic..?

Comment: i just did a google search and this qestion popped up as first result so even if there are 100 questions like that google thinks its worth to rank it #1

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Add this bit to your code (preferably at the end of whatever inserts you have):

```
    var psconsole = $('#one');
    if(psconsole.length)
       psconsole.scrollTop(psconsole[0].scrollHeight - psconsole.height());
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks, no val remove and add b*llsh*t, however one comment. The length you checked is the length of the object array inside jQuery object, I think you need to notice this with a comment that it is safe to use psconsole[0]. Maybe some people think it is the length of contents and that's not true. I think you also need to add a second condition to check scrollheight is a number (it is used on a scrollable thing) and after this check apply the calculation.

Answer (score 11):

See this Live Demo: [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/tGFmq/1/)

To calculate the bottom `scrollTop`, you can simply *subtract* the `height` from the `scrollHeight`:

```
var oneDiv = $("#one");
bottom = oneDiv.prop('scrollHeight') - oneDiv.height()
```

Then you can set its scrollTop to `bottom`, or use amazing [**jQuery's *`animate()`***](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for cool animation.

Live Demo: [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/tGFmq/1/)

Comment: This worked great for need, appending a textarea from user input, when full it would nicely animate down to show they are still adding to the list. thx :)

Answer (score 4):

I realised my problem was that I had the code in the incorrect place. -> Placed under the element and got the problem to solve (rookie mistake....) -- Just a reminder to all.